# Application loads slowly when deployed on shiny server pro

Tags: r

I know that when the application is slow, there are multiple reasons like code not optimized and calling data from databases,

But the issue, I am using R shiny server pro.
The very small simple application (plotting the histogram) when loaded locally it is super fast. But when deployed on shiny server pro, it is taking time. Why is this? I understand when the code is huge and there might be delay because of this.

But this is a simple application with 10 lines of code (both UI and server) and acts slowly when deployed on shiny server pro.

Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: It's always going to be slower when deployed on a remote server compared to the server being your computer itself. How much slower is it?

Comment: now for this simple application its a bit slow, (by 3 - 5 sec). But for larger app (it is slow by  more 10 sec ). Especially the slowness is more at the of loading the application. Say when i open the app locally, within 1 sec it opens, but on server, it takes 5 sec. And also during filtering.

Comment: That's not particularly uncommon. What are the specs of the server?

Comment: its shiny server pro with more than 500 users. Not sure about memory. Is there a way to see this using linux command?

Comment: These will be questions for the admins of your server, I think. I would check whether enough resources are being allocated to deploy apps.